# How to solve this kind of ordinary differential equations $t y y^{\prime \prime}-2 t\left(y^{\prime}\right)^{2}+3 y y^{\prime}=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Often, to solve an ODE, it if enough to classify it correctly and apply correspondent well-known method. But in this case I struggle

$t y y^{\prime \prime}-2 t\left(y^{\prime}\right)^{2}+3 y y^{\prime}=0$

It is non-linear homogeneous second-order ODE with variable coefficients. In textbooks, people talk about similar equations where one variable is missing (x or y or y'). In that case, we use substitution like y = z(z) or y' = p(x). But in my ODE, I do not see what to do.

Comment: $yy''$ and $y'^2$ together hint at a second derivative of $u=y^\alpha$, here $\alpha=-1$ seems to work. This should reduce the equation to a simple case. If not, chances are high that no symbolic solution exists, as is the case for almost all DE of a random structure with random coefficients.

Comment: @Vasile : this will not work in the last term. But one could divide by $tyy'$ to get all terms integrable.

Comment: **Hint** Let $y(x)=e^{z(x)}$ and it will be simple.

Comment: You have right! Actualy I proposed $u=\frac{y}{y'}$. I made a mistake!

Comment: @Vasile : Yes, that would also work. Non-linear DE in general need a very rigid structure to be symbolically solvable, this often opens multiple approaches for the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$t y y^{\prime \prime}-2 t\left(y^{\prime}\right)^{2}+3 y y^{\prime}=0$$
$$t y y^{\prime \prime}+3 y y^{\prime}=2 t\left(y^{\prime}\right)^{2}$$
Multiply both sides by $t^2$:
$$t^3 y y^{\prime \prime}+3t^2 y y^{\prime}=2 t^3\left(y^{\prime}\right)^{2}$$
$$y(t^3y')'=2t^3y'^2$$
$$\dfrac {(t^3y')'}{t^3y'}=2\dfrac {y'}{y}$$
$$\dfrac {(t^3y')'}{t^3y'}=2(\ln y)'$$
$$(\ln t^3y')'=2(\ln y)'$$
You can now reduce the order of the DE by integration.
$$\ln (t^3y')=2\ln (y)+C_1$$
$$t^3y'=Cy^2$$
The DE is separable.

Answer (score 0):

Hint,

$$
\frac{y''}{y'}-2\frac{y'}{y}+\frac 3t = 0
$$

or

$$
(\ln y')'-2(\ln y)'-3(\ln t)' = 0
$$

then

$$
\ln\left(\frac{y't^3}{y^2}\right)=C
$$

Comment: Thanks! So many things to notice! It is a quite useful equivalence with $ln$; I should remember it.